# Moving a detailed literature survey in Appendix to reduce size of chapter?

Tags: thesis

In my dissertation, I am solving a problem by using techniques used to solve another problem. As a result, I have to do two literature surveys for both problems. I ended up with a huge chapter!  - most of it is basically a literature survey.

I do not want my examiners to hate me when they find a long thesis, but I don't want to get comments such as: "Why have you not considered the work of X in your survey?"

Is it a good practice to move part of this huge chapter's survey to an Appendix chapter, while keeping a section that speaks about the general approaches followed in the literature?

Answer (score 6):

For a thesis, you may as well include the full review. You've done the work, and a thesis typically has no particular length limit. Realistically, your examiners will probably just skim it anyway. I see no reason to move it to an appendix, though I also don't think it matters very much. If your advisor or university policies feel strongly, of course, do what they say.

When you publish papers based on your thesis, then you'll want to condense the review to focus on  the most important and relevant prior work.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** I am a current graduate student starting to write my own doctoral dissertation.

The advice which I have got from several faculty members with whom I have been working for the last 3-4 years is that there is no *true* length to a literature review.

A literature survey should encapsulate your research problem, identify the current gap in the literature and then, factor in methods using which you attempt to answer your research question.

If that makes it long, its long. My literature review is probably around ~30-40 pages. Given that I work in a rather interdisciplinary area, its inevitable.

I advise you to include all the literature that is relevant.

The appendix is usually reserved for additional figures, tables, links, code, supplementary analysis etc.